# Swiftmailer unable to authenticate to GMail using oauth2 token

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer, smtp-auth

I'm trying to use SwiftMailer to log in to a GMail account for which I have a valid access token. I can successfully login using the account credentials:

```
$Transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com',587,'tls');
$Transport->setAuthMode('login')
          ->setUsername('my-email-address')
          ->setPassword('my-password');

$Mailer = new Swift_Mailer($Transport);
// ... make a new message & send it
```

However if I change the code to use my oauth2 token like so:

```
$access_token = 'ya29.GLv....'; 
$Transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com',587,'tls');
$Transport->setAuthMode('XOAUTH2')
          ->setUsername('my-email-address')
          ->setPassword($access_token);

$Mailer = new Swift_Mailer($Transport);
```

I get an error message: `Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "535".... Username and Password are not accepted.`

I'm using the same access token elsewhere using the GMail API, so I know the token is valid.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

Just ran the code again with the debugger turned on.  It looks like the first error code thrown is 334 with the message:

```
Expected response code 235 but got code "334", with message "334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
```

The encoded part of that message decodes to:

```
{"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
```

Comment: Did you get a breakthrough! Am dying with the same issue

Comment: No, I never got a breakthrough.  My desire to use Swiftmailer was so that I could use it to generate the mime for the email message.  I'm still able to use Swift_Message and Swift_Message->toString() to do that, then just use Service->users_messages->send() to actually send the message.  Connection is still done through the gawdawful Google library.

Comment: I managed to get it working after many tries. The issues was that I have insufficient permissions. So swiftmailer would fail with no elaborate message... I used the default GoogleClient to diagnose the issue and then swiftmailer just worked. Let me leave an answer for someone who might be having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The biggest hurdle that you might face and no one is talking about is **insufficient permissions**. SwiftMailer doesn't do a good job elaborating this issue; therefore you might want to use GoogleClient to make sure you credentials are working before using them with SwiftMailer.

**[Full source code](https://github.com/mtvbrianking/gmail-xoauth)**

```
# Using SwiftMailer

// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'tls'))
    ->setAuthMode('XOAUTH2')
    ->setUsername('<SENDER_EMAIL>')
    ->setPassword('<ACCESS_TOKEN>');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message())
    ->setFrom(['<SENDER_EMAIL>' => '<SENDER_NAME>'])
    ->setTo(explode(';', '<RECEIVER_EMAIL>'))
    ->setSubject('<SUBJECT')
    ->setBody('<MESSGAE_BODY>');

// Send the message
if ($mailer->send($message)) {
    print 'Mail sent...';
    exit();
}

echo('Mail not sent...');
```